# Add an encoding declaration

Tags: c#

I am getting run time error. Please help!

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlDeclaration decNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", ENCODING, string.Empty); 

XmlAttribute encodeAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("encoding");

encodeAttr.InnerText = "utf-8";

decNode.Attributes.Append(encodeAttr);

doc.AppendChild(decNode);

doc.AppendChild(decNode);
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

i don't see anything other than ENCODING in your code. you can pass it null like this

```
 XmlDeclaration decNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
```

or if you want to specify one you can use one from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

```
XmlDeclaration decNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
```